# UIImagePickerController 16*9 screen on IPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController on IPad and I'm looking for a way to enable the bottom and top black bar to have a 16/9 screen instead of 4/3 by default.

These bars can be display when double tapping on the screen but I can't find a way to show them programmatically.

As you can see on the screenshot bellow, it is important that the layer fit the screen.

**Without the bars**
[image]

**With the bars**
[image]

Comment: You can try to draw these bars on custom `UIView`, and than use `cameraOverlayView ` property of `UIImagePickerController` to set it in place.